# Слово "дно" во множественном числе

Tags: грамматика, множественное-число

Как выглядит слово "дно" во множественном числе?

- Одно **дно**
- Два **дна**
- Три **дна**
- Четыре **дна**
- Пять **???**

Я знаю правильный ответ, но не знаю **почему так**. Хотелось бы услышать аргументированный ответ, подкрепленный цитатами и ссылками на весомые источники.

Comment: Из правил:
You should only ask practical, answerable questions(...) Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness(...)

Comment: This question seems fine to me as is. Asking for reasons behind word usage is certainly a step above just asking for the right form of the word to use.

Comment: Почему не рассматривается вариант: пять днов?

Comment: I have found this helpful website which agrees with пять доньев: https://en.openrussian.org/ru/дно

Comment: I found this website to be helpful as well: https://www.russiandict.net It looks a bit more modern in terms of UI.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Множественное число слова "дно" - донья. Дна - это родительный падеж.

Числительные два, три, четыре (а также составные числительные, оканчивающиеся на два, три, четыре, например двадцать два) в именительном падеже сочетаются с существительным в форме родительного падежа и единственного числа.

Источники:

- http://slovari.299.ru/word.php?find_word=%E4%ED%EE&slovar=4
- http://feb-web.ru/feb/mas/mas-abc/05/ma140613.htm
- http://slovari.yandex.ru/~книги/Толковый%20словарь%20Даля/ДНО/
- http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_92

Comment: Это предложение взято по 3-ей ссылке "В бочке клепки дубовые, а оба дна сосновые". Значит всё таки 2,3,4 **дна**? Значит **дна** тоже множественная форма или я что-то упустил... Выходит 2 множественные формы у слова?

Comment: Нет, это поэтическая вольность.

Comment: Это не вольность, а правило русского языка: Числительные два, три, четыре (а также составные числительные, оканчивающиеся на два, три, четыре, например двадцать два) в именительном падеже сочетаются с существительным в форме родительного падежа и единственного числа.

http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_92

Comment: @xyzman это должно быть ответом.

Comment: @kotekzot - предлагаю вам расширить свой ответ ("Дна - это родительный падеж"), ведь про множественное число "донья" вы правы.

Comment: @xyzman спасибо, так и сделал.

Comment: Форма _"дна"_, только сочетается с родительным падежом, но не является родительным падежом.  Это пережиток двойственного числа в русском языке. [Двойственное число](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE) Пример: _"Два брата живут рядом."_  Это именительный падеж.

Answer (score 7):

I don't have any well-founded answer, but [Zalizniak's dictionary](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/morph.cgi?word=%5Bdno%5D) says that both **пять доньев** and **пять дён** are correct.

Comment: "дён" (устар.) is more likely the plural form for "день". Пример: От бурлацких артелей тех времён дошла до наших дней поговорка: «Идём семь дён – Симбирск видён».

Comment: The dictionary you are referring to does not include *дён*.  It gives Variant 1: _*де’н_, without ë. The asterisk means a theoretical form not actually attested; you might call it _regular_, since it follows a pattern, but it is definitely not _correct_.